# How to use Context when getting a direction with GO?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-golang

I'm having the following code to get the direction from Google Cloud:

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

const directionAPIKey = "APIKey"
const directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%s&destination=%s&mode=%s&key=%s"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    direction, err := fetchDirection(ctx, r.FormValue("origin"), r.FormValue("destination"), r.FormValue("mode"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Write(direction)
}

func fetchDirection(ctx appengine.Context, origin string, destination string, mode string) ([]byte, error) {
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    resp, err := client.Get(fmt.Sprintf(directionURL, origin, destination, mode, directionAPIKey))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    return ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
}
```

But I get an error:

> undefined: appengine.Context

When trying to deploy the app. What I have tried is to change:

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
```

into

```
ctx := r.Context()
```

And

```
func fetchDirection(ctx appengine.Context, origin string...)
```

into

```
func fetchDirection(ctx Context, origin string...)
```

But I get:

```
undefined: Context
```

I'm completely lost. I'm new to Go and GCP, so please be patient with me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [godoc for urlfetch](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch#Client) you'll see it links to [where the Context type is defined](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context). That in turn tells you that "As of Go 1.7 this package is available in the standard library under the name context. https://golang.org/pkg/context."

So add an import:

```
import "context"
```

and refer to it as:

```
func fetchDirection(ctx context.Context, origin string...)
```

Comment: Hi aviraldg and thanks for the time you took to answer my question. I did what you said and it's true that the app is deployed fine now, however, as a result, I do **not** get the JSON file with the actual direction as it supposed to get, I only get displayed [Get https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=&destination=&mode=&key=APIKey not an App Engine context](https://i.ibb.co/xGrtXG3/Capture.jpg). Do you have any suggestion on that?

Comment: You might have to fix your main() function following: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences#writing_a_main_package